# a problem when i try to add flutter path(zsh: permission denied: /Users/saitdogu/.zshrc)

Tags: flutter, terminal, path, sdk, flutter-path

I'm new on flutter and just downloaded sdk to my mac m2. I did all the things from flutter offical page but i couldn't add the path yet.
Can someone help me?
thanks.[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPpeh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the file with using `sudo` prefix to grant permission.